# Multiple delete in nodejs mysql using checkboxes

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

How do you perform multiple delete in nodeJs MySql? Where I need to check check-boxes to select the id's to be deleted in my blogger form.

**front end**

    <% for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) { %>

```
        </td>
        <td> <%= data[i].catname %> </td>
        <td> <%= data[i].status %> </td>
        <td> <%= data[i].id %> </td>
        <td> <a href="/delete/<%= data[i].id %>"> delete</a></td>
        <td> <a href="/view/<%= data[i].id %>"> view</a></td>
        <td> <a href="/update/<%= data[i].id %>"> update</a></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="data[i].id">delete <%=data[i].id %>  </td>

        <!-- making checkboxes -->


                        </tr>
```

**back-end**
app.post('/deletechecks',function(req,res){

```
var ch= req.body.check;
console.log(ch);
for(i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
{
    var h= "delete from mydata where id='"+ch[i]+"''";
    con.query(h,function(err,result){
        if(submit==deleteselected)
        {
        console.log("deleted");
  }
    });

}
res.redirect('/viewdata');
```

});p.s i dont know what to do after this.

Comment: Kindly share if you are using `Sequelize` or something else ?

Comment: first of all, res.redirect outside the callback in your query will do the redirection before the query is executed.
Second. I am assuming you have a button somewhere, on whose click you will call the node POST api?
in which case i dont see any Logical issues with your code.
if your question is how to do run a query in node-mysql adpater, i dont see any issues in your code either for that.
if your question is regarding how to actually perform a delete operation in my sql, your query "delete from mydata where id".. sounds accurate to me.
not surewhat to help you on.

Answer (score 0):

So hi there it's bit late while I am answering this .
So same situation I was there but the DB I was using was Mongo.
In my case it was a TO-DO list app where the user need to have a functionality of multipple delete so there were checkboxes were provided before the tasks.
I will attach a screenshot also for refernce.
While figuring it what I did I made a form there and first selected all task that I want to mark as done in case first and then hit delete so basically all will be deleted at once .
What happened I added a field 'name' in each task whose value I filled with the ObjectID in DB in order to make it unique OKAY! (As in the home page via EJS i had that info precomputed with me) (By EJS i mean View part or templating engine)
As once the Delete Button would be pressed (basically Submit) button then all these task values would be appended inside req.body (I think this you understad ) so what I did I casted the string values to ObjectID and called delete on the ID's .
So Now I am sending the pic and then code if still any issues in this do ask.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R08sY.jpg) The UI that I was talking above that will make things clear

And this is the delete function for reference :
Code:

```
app.post('/deleteTasks',function(req,resp){
   let targetTask = req.body;
   console.log('Hello there',targetTask);

   let obj = [];
   for(itr in targetTask){
        const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
        const _id = ObjectId(itr);
        obj.push(_id);
   }
   console.log(obj);
 
   for(itr of obj){
      Task.findByIdAndDelete(itr,function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log('Error occured ',err.message);
          return;
       }
      });
   }
  
        return resp.redirect('back');      
    
  
});
```

Hope this can help and you can do some subsequent changes as per your quest .